# Pagination is not working properly in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I am novice in Codeigniter and I am working on pagination. But there is something wrong in my code. What mistake I have been done in the following code? 
I have attached my code snippet below.

**Route**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages";
$route['default_controller/(:num)'] = "pages/index/$1";
```

**Controller**

```
public function index($page='home')

    {

       if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
        }



        $config=[

            'base_url' => base_url().'/pages/index',
            'per_page' => 5,
            'total_rows' =>$this->products_model->record_count()
        ];

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
        $data['products'] = $this->products_model->get_products($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

        $data['request'] = 'pages/home';
        $this->load->view('templates/content',$data);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function get_products($limit, $offset)
{
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $query=$this->db->get('product'); 
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function record_count($value='')
{
    return $this->db->count_all("product");
}
```

**View**

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links() ?>
```

In the View, I am displaying the records from a table. The first page of records displays, but when I click the second page it shows Error

```
"**404 Page Not Found**"
```

Any kind of help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the records you are expecting to see?  Are there more than 5?

Comment: Yes off course. there is 30+ records i have. But when i click on 2nd page of pagination. Page not found error display

Comment: Can you post the code for your buttons too?  It could be that.  Or, what is the value of `$page` when you get a 404?  Maybe that file doesn't exist.

Comment: `$this->pagination->create_links();` function create buttons automatically in Codeigniter. and the  value of `$page` is 'home'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your logic, the line "index($page='home') the index method gets the script to display from the parameter passed to it. On the first load, the default page, 'home.php' is matched, but when you select the second page, the CI router and index function look for maybe '1.php' or '2.php' and so on, depending on your paging, do those files exist for every page you request? Otherwise, you should instead check if the page variable is a valid page (e.g non-negative) then continue execution and load the results to your view

Comment: yes, you are right @Peter M. i have created another method and route . and it works fine